# Random variable $X \sim \mathcal N(m,m^2)$ question

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

A random variable $X \sim \mathcal N(m,m^2)$ in a population, with $m \in \Bbb R^+$. In what percentage of the population, the variable has a positive value?.

I don't know how to start this problem, i thought it depends of the value of $m$, but apparently not.

Any hints? I never worked with a normal distribution with $\mu=\sigma$

Comment: They are asking about $P(X > 0).$ If you have never work with $\mu = \sigma,$ then assume $X \sim \mathrm{Norm}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu > 0$ and find $P(X > 0)$ (using a table) then substitute $\mu = \sigma = m.$

Comment: Thanks, i did it.